# Two-dimensional generalization of Leibniz's integral rule

Tags: integration, partial-derivative, multiple-integral, leibniz-integral-rule, transport-equation

Given a function $f(x,y):\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ and a real parameter $\theta$, one can use Leibniz's integral rule to solve
\begin{equation}\label{eq}\tag{1}\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}dx \ f(x,y)= b'(\theta)f(b(\theta),y) -  a'(\theta)f(a(\theta),y). \end{equation}
Notice that $f$ does not depend itself on $\theta$, and therefore there is no integral term in the RHS.

I am interested in the generalization of $(1)$ in the two-dimensional case, where $f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y): \mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ is integrated over a region $S(\theta)$ whose geometry depends on $\theta$ (for example, this might be the radius of a circle, or the edge of a square). As far as I understand, Leibniz's rule in three dimension is related to [Reynold's transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem), according to which given a function $f(\mathbf x, \theta)$ over a region $\Omega(\theta)$ with moving boundary $\partial\Omega(\theta)$ it holds that
\begin{equation}\label{2}\tag{2}
\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{\Omega(\theta)}f \ dV=\int_{\Omega(\theta)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\ dV + \int_{\partial\Omega(\theta)}(\mathbf v_b\cdot \mathbf n)f\ dA
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf v_b$ is the velocity of the area element and $\mathbf n$ the normal vector.

However, my situation is a bit different. First of all, since $f$ does not depend on the parameter $\theta$, the first integral in the RHS is zero. Secondly, since I care about the 2D case, I should be able to rewrite $(2)$ as something like
$$\tag{3}\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{S(\theta)}f \ dA= \int_{\partial S(\theta)}(\mathbf v_b\cdot \mathbf n)f \ dl.$$
Is $(3)$ valid under my hypotheses, and if so, is there any way to make the scalar product $\mathbf v_b \cdot \mathbf n$ more explicit without fixing a specific geometry?

Comment: At some point down the road you might be interested in the Reynolds transport theorem.

Comment: @Aruralreader I don't understand this comment.

Comment: Is your $S(\theta)$ a 2D surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (or perhaps some other ambient space $M$), or is your setup that you have some abstract 2-dimensional surface $\Sigma$, and your $S(\theta)$ is a family of surfaces within this 2-dimensional space $\Sigma$? In the latter case, your (3) would be right, but in the former case, no (google the *first variation of area/volume* formula). Also, what do you mean by *‘is there any way to make the scalar product more explicit without fixing a specific geometry’*?

Comment: If you are not going to make any use of $y$ in a formula, there was no reason to include a reference to it. The Leibniz formula for functions independent of $\theta$ is more cleanly stated as $f : \Bbb R \to\Bbb C$ and $$\frac{d}{d\theta}\int_{a(\theta)}^{b(\theta)}dx \ f(x)= b'(\theta)f(b(\theta)) -  a'(\theta)f(a(\theta))$$ With similar remarks concerning your 2D version. The second variable usually included is $\theta$, not some other $y$. To see that Reynold's transport theorem applies to your case, just define $\Omega(\theta) = S(\theta)\times [0,1]$ and integrate $g(x,y,z) = f(x,y)$.